# How to convert one object json to array object json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

My object json is like this :

```
var a = [{
    "attributes": {
        "Code": "SGL",
        "Total": "811400"
    },
    "DayPrice": {
        "Date": "2016-07-22",
        "Rate": "811400"
    }
}];
```

I want change DayPrice to array like this :

```
var a = [{
    "attributes": {
        "Code": "SGL",
        "Total": "811400"
    },
    "DayPrice": [{
        "Date": "2016-07-22",
        "Rate": "811400"
    }]
}];
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to loop through the array of objects and wrap the `DayPrice` property of each in an array, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].DayPrice = [a[i].DayPrice];
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3y2wwj3k/)

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870

Answer (score 2):

Assign the an array with the property to the property.

```
a[1].DayPrice = [a[1].DayPrice];
```

Or use a loop:

```js
var a = [{ "attributes": { "Code": "SGL", "Total": "811400" }, "DayPrice": { "Date": "2016-07-22", "Rate": "811400" } }];

a.forEach(function (a) {
    if ('DayPrice' in a) {
        a.DayPrice = [a.DayPrice];
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
var a = [{
            "attributes": {
                "Code": "SGL",
                "Total": "811400"
            },
            "DayPrice": {
                "Date": "2016-07-22",
                "Rate": "811400"
            }
        }];

var _getDayPrice = a[0].DayPrice;

var _dayPriceArray = [];
_dayPriceArray.push({
  "Date":_getDayPrice.Date,
  "Rate":_getDayPrice.Rate
})
a[0].DayPrice=_dayPriceArray;
console.log(a);
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kavxatro/)

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870